# Generating a collection from mainframe fields in Blue Prism RPA

Tags: blueprism, rpa

We're currently using the Rocket PC to Host client with our business object, and we have created all the items to read 16 fields from a specific mainframe screen.  We're building a collection from these inputs by looping through and adding them individually to a collection.

Is there any way in Blue Prism to collect these fields directly into a collection, removing the necessity to parse these individually and add them row by row into the collection?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the functionality you describe does not exist within Blue Prism. You'll have to populate the fields manually.

This is due simply to the unstructured nature of the data presented by the mainframe to Blue Prism.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data directly from a read step to a collection, then you should create a field in your collection as text. Then in read step input your collection by CollectionName.FieldName, see picture.

Hope this answered your question, else please give an example of your problem.

[image: Read from terminal to collection]